How to design a network and loss function for classes, composed of two other classes?
Given an image-dataset of three classes, A, B and C, where C is a composition of A and B, we want to train a classifier that predicts:

A, if only A is present
B if only B is present
C if both A and B are present.

How can we design the final classification layer as well as the loss function?
I thought about thresholding class C, even with a learnable threshold, but that would be highly influenced by the class distribution in the dataset.

This sounds like a multilabel problem where you predict a binary A/not and a separate binary B/not, with C being the combination of both A and B being present. That is, you have a bivariate outcome. Bivariate probit would be the starting algorithm. With images, I suspect you will be interested in convolutional neural networks. Fortunately, extensions to deep learning architectures do exist and have software implementations ready to go.
The keyword to search, either for underlying theory or for code, however, is a multilabel problem.
A question of mine concerning multilabel problems

Since $p(C)=p(A \cap B) = p(A=1,B=1)$.
you can then design two networks:
\begin{cases}
\nu_1=p(A)\\
\nu_2=p(B\mid A=a)
\end{cases}
This means the second network take an additional input: the occurrence (or not) of $A$.
Then $p(C)=\nu_1 \nu_2$, and you can simply maximize likelihood as usual.

You can also directly model $p(A,B)$, since you have only four possible outcomes, with an energy based model.
$$p(A,B) = \frac{\exp(-\eta(A,B))}{Z},$$
where $\eta(A,B)$ is the energy, a positive quantity estimated by a neural network that takes the image and the two events as inputs, and $Z$ is the normalization constant (or partition function in thermodynamics), given by the sum of the energy associated with all four events.

If you were to write down the resulting joint probability, you will notice it amounts to treating the problem as a four classes classification problem, with $\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ classes.
You can then take the leap and frame the problem as such, allowing you to directly estimate the probabilities, bypassing the needs for conditional modelling or structuring an energy-based formulation.
